# File.ReadAllText(): System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path is denied.'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.essentials

Here is a snippet of the code I'm having issues with:

```cs
public OpenPage(string filePath, int? index, object jobject)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            File.SetAttributes(filePath, FileAttributes.Normal); // Here is where error in title occurs
            var readText = File.ReadAllText(filePath); // Also occurs here
            
            DisplayAlert("Alert", readText, "Ok");      
        }
```

I'm creating a UWP Xamarin.Forms application which needs to read a file from a selected directory (anything on the C: drive). Although I'm getting the error in the title when I don't choose files from the local cache / AppData.

Looking at other similar posts in StackOverflow (such as [Why is access to the path denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821410/why-is-access-to-the-path-denied)) was great for learning more about the subject, although many questions regarding this error are outdated.

In the post above, one person said that a directory cannot be passed as File.ReadAllText()'s parameter.

Is there any work around to this? I need access to files on the C: drive. For reference, the filePath in the constructor when I was debugging was ""C:\Users\ianpc\Desktop\config file clones\te0_ptt_wog.json".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33082835/windows-10-universal-app-file-directory-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any work around to this? I need access to files on the C: drive. For reference, the filePath in the constructor when I was debugging was ""C:\Users\ianpc\Desktop\config file clones\te0_ptt_wog.json".

The problem is UWP app runs in sandbox environment, so we can't use  `System.IO` namespace to access file with path directly.

For xamarin forms app, we suggest you use Windows Storage api to access file with path and before that, you need enable `broadFileSystemAccess` capability.

For example

```
public interface FileAccessInterface
{
    Task<string> GetFileText(string filePath);
}
```

**Implementation**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(FileAccessInterfaceImplementation))]
namespace XamarinPicker.UWP
{
    public class FileAccessInterfaceImplementation : FileAccessInterface
    {
        public async Task<string> GetFileText(string filePath)
        {
            var stringContent = "";
            try
            {
                var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath);
               
                if (file != null)
                {
                    stringContent = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file,Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            return stringContent;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var text = await DependencyService.Get<FileAccessInterface>().GetFileText(@"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\test.txt");
```

For more please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345579/7254781).

Comment: I'll give this implementation a go; thanks so much for the information!

Comment: I'm actually getting an error: 'IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IAsyncOperation<StorageFile>' could be found (are you missing a using directive for 'System'?). Although at the top of my file I have a using System statement. I'll be looking into this problem on other posts but if you have a fix for this it'd be super useful!

Comment: It looks you missed `System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll` library, please refer this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62381819/7254781) and add it manually.